# How to do prefix search on names / titles

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Suppose I've got a users table with uid and name fields. How do I, efficiently, do prefix matches (for auto-complete) with all words in a name?

I could do `select uid from users where name like '% spek%` but that doesn't seem very efficient (and I'd have to prepend a space to all names.

I can't simply use '%spek%' because a name or title could consist of multiple words.
Input 'olaf spek' should also match name 'olaf van der spek'.

The table might have 500 000 rows.
The space trick assumes words are separated by spaces.

Comment: i'd say a naive optimization would be to have a table that holds only words (eg. 'van', 'der', 'spek') and a table that links your word table to your full-sentence table ('olaf van der spek'). You would then only search the word table for matches, and upon match, retrieve the full-sentence linked to this match..?

Comment: Why don't use fulltext index?  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/fulltext-index-overview/

Comment: @GeorgRichter It doesn't do prefix searching, "Geo" doesn't match "Georg".

Comment: But it does: `AGAINST ('geo*')`